# Portable device to create electromagnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism

I am writing a novel, set in 1960. For the story line I need a small device that can deliver a strong electromagnetic field.

Was there such a device in 1960? Could one have been easily built? The character who will use it will have access to physics and/or engineering labs at a university.

Nothing too technical please. The simpler the device the better. My readers won't be able to handle much math or science,  I'm afraid (to be honest, nor can I).

Thanks for all the help you can provide! 
This is such a cool site. I've spent time away from my writing just to enjoy what I am learning here!

Thanks again!

Comment: Radio emitter / receiver? Candle? Light / radiation is an electromagnetic field.

Comment: Also a static charge or a magnet.

Comment: Define "small", define "strong". An A-bomb generates EMP. See [W54](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W54).

Comment: What effect do you envision the device having in your story? "strong" is quite vague

Comment: Going for a Van de Graaff generator! I'm not ready to reveal my story yet, but you will all be credited in my acknowledgements. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That depends what kind of electromagnetic field you want to create. If any will do, then simply a regular flashlight would suffice. A laser would produce a stronger field. If you want a steady magnetic field, a magnet (perhaps with a coil of wire with current going through it wrapped around it) would do. If you want a strong steady electric field, consider a [Van de Graaff generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_de_Graaff_generator).

Comment: Looks like the Van de Graaff will do the trick for the story. From what I've seen online, they are small enough to be portable, and powerful enough to achieve the goal of my character. Sorry I don't want to reveal the story line yet, but you will all be credited for your help in my acknowledgements. What a great resource you all are!